# R - Repetitions of an array in other array

Tags: r

From a dataframe I get a new array, sliced from a dataframe.
I want to get the amount of times a certain repetition appears on it.

For example

```
main <- c(A,B,C,A,B,V,A,B,C,D,E)
p <- c(A,B,C)
q <- c(A,B)

someFunction(main,p)
2

someFunction(main,q)
3
```

I've been messing around with `rle` but it counts every subrepetion also, undersirable.

Is there a quick solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the regular expression tools in R since this is really a pattern matching exercise, specifically `gregexpr` for this question. The `p` and `q` vectors represent the search pattern and `main` is where we want to search for those patterns. From the help page for `gregexpr`:

```
gregexpr returns a list of the same length as text each element of which is of 
the same form as the return value for regexpr, except that the starting positions 
of every (disjoint) match are given.
```

So we can take the length of the first list returned by `gregexpr` which gives the starting positions of the matches. We'll first collapse the vectors and then do the searching:

```
someFunction <- function(haystack, needle) {
    haystack <- paste(haystack, collapse = "")
    needle <- paste(needle, collapse = "")
    out <- gregexpr(needle, haystack)
    out.length <- length(out[[1]])
    return(out.length)
}

> someFunction(main, p)
[1] 2
> someFunction(main, q)
[1] 3
```

Note - you also need to throw "" around your vector `main`, `p`, and `q` vectors unless you have variables A, B, C, et al defined.

```
main <- c("A","B","C","A","B","V","A","B","C","D","E")
p <- c("A","B","C")
q <- c("A","B")
```

Comment: Nice, and it works with the example data. But it might not work with all input, because of the collapse you do.  What happens when you want to search for `c(1,2,3)` in `c(1,2,3,123)`?

Comment: Good call. Luckily I can't have that input, but it is indeed a problem.

Comment: @Chase solution should work if you collapse using (say) a "." rather than "".

Comment: Yes, but then you assume that your search string will never contain a ".".  In general, I am extremely wary of solutions that involve transforming the data.  Yes, sometimes it's difficult to avoid, but not in this case.

Comment: @Andrie - so what's the expected result in your second example?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but you can simply do that work by:

```
f <- function(a,b) 
  if (length(a) > length(b)) 0 
  else all(head(b, length(a)) == a) + Recall(a, tail(b, -1))
```

Someone may or may not find a built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sapply`:

```
find_x_in_y <- function(x, y){
  sum(sapply(
      seq_len(length(y)-length(x)),
      function(i)as.numeric(all(y[i:(i+length(x)-1)]==x))
  ))
}


find_x_in_y(c("A", "B", "C"), main)
[1] 2

find_x_in_y(c("A", "B"), main)
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using `embed(v,n)`, which returns a matrix of all `n`-length sub-sequences of vector `v`:

```
find_x_in_y <- function(x, y) 
                   sum( apply( embed( y, length(x)), 1, 
                                  identical, rev(x)))

> find_x_in_y(p, main)
[1] 2
> find_x_in_y(q, main)
[1] 3
```